# How can I add "row position" to a query with a SUM(…) column from subquery?

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions

I am getting a weird error when I try to get SUM(…) column in a subquery and then get row "indexes":

```
WITH lb(displayName, val) AS (
    SELECT user.displayName, SUM(stats.weight) AS val FROM stats
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON user.id = stats.userId
    GROUP BY user.id
    ORDER BY val DESC
)
SELECT displayName, val, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lb b WHERE a.val <= b.val) AS position FROM lb a
```

The error I get when I run it in [SQLiteBrowser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser) is:
`misuse of aggregate: SUM():` followed by the full text of the query.

However, the query works fine if I either:

- remove the `, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lb b WHERE a.val <= b.val) AS position` from the final SELECT;
- do not use SUM.

(but I do need both)

**Here is the (working) example (sqlfiddle), where the row index is missing (it also includes some test data):** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b1cc3/1/0

How can I fix it, so it would work (that means, add row numbers to the result set)?

I need these indexes because I'm going to add a WHERE clause after this query, and I need to know the order of the rows which were retained.

For example, the wanted result for the test data in the fiddle above is:

```
| displayName |  val | position |
|-------------|------|----------|
|       name2 | 1256 |        1 |
|       name4 |  133 |        2 |
|       name5 |   62 |        3 |
|       name3 |   43 |        4 |
```

(position could as well start with 0, it's not important)

P.S. replacing the SQL implementation (SQLite) with something else is not an option (at least not right now)

Comment: Works for me (3.8.12). Please note that the ORDER BY must be on the outer query.

Comment: @CL. I tried moving ORDER BY to the outer query, the query still breaks, with the same error. Let me check the version…

Comment: The two sentences in my first comment are independent.

Comment: @CL. I tried with command-line sqlite3 and it worked. So, both sqlfiddle and sqlitebrowser are using an outdated implementation then? And also thank you for the hint.

Comment: @CL. > "The two sentences in my first comment are independent." — Got it. Why must the ORDER BY be on the outer query?

Comment: Without it, the database is allowed to optimize the outer query in a way that could change the order.

Comment: Thank you again! Your help is great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [CL.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl)'s comments, it became clear that the query is working on a more recent version of SQLite.

So the problem is likely that sqlitebrowser (and sqlfiddle, too) use an outdated version of SQLite. (I opened [an issue in sqlitebrowser repository](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/457) about this problem)